# View Class Diagram Missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In Visual Studio 2015, the view option is missing `class diagram` as represented in the following image. 
[image]
I have tried `Enterprise Architect` but that software is unable to detect `C# 6` syntax. For example whenever there's `public static String readonlyText => "123";`, it skips the class.

What's the solution to generate class diagram based on ASP.Net Core code?

Answer (score 2):

In Class View (Ctrl+Shift+C) Right click a namespace or class, and you should see the 'View Class Diagram' option. Useless tho, nothing happens when you click it.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably not working in previous versions, Now in 'Class View' (Ctrl-Shift-C), right click a namespace or class, then click 'View Class Diagram' which creates a new class diagram in the root folder of your project.

[Contextual menu in the 'Class View pane'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmqd0.png)

This works at least in the last edition of VS community edition:

[Version in which the feature is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSHqu.png)

The new class diagram file, starts empty though.